# Levenshtein distance c# count error type

Tags: c#, count, levenshtein-distance

I found this bit of code that computes [Levenshtein's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between an answer and a guess:

```
int CheckErrors(string Answer, string Guess)
{
    int[,] d = new int[Answer.Length + 1, Guess.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= Answer.Length; i++)
        d[i, 0] = i;
    for (int j = 0; j <= Guess.Length; j++)
        d[0, j] = j;
    for (int j = 1; j <= Guess.Length; j++)
        for (int i = 1; i <= Answer.Length; i++)
            if (Answer[i - 1] == Guess[j - 1])
                d[i, j] = d[i - 1, j - 1];  //no operation
            else
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(
                    d[i - 1, j] + 1,    //a deletion

                    d[i, j - 1] + 1),   //an insertion

                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + 1 //a substitution

                );
    return d[Answer.Length, Guess.Length];
}
```

But I need a way to do a count for the amount of times each error occurs. Is there an easy way to implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you could add counters for each of the operations:

```
                if (Answer[i - 1] == Guess[j - 1])
                    d[i, j] = d[i - 1, j - 1];  //no operation
                else
                {
                    int del = d[i-1, j] + 1;
                    int ins = d[i, j-1] + 1;
                    int sub = d[i-1, j-1] + 1;
                    int op = Math.Min(Math.Min(del, ins), sub);
                    d[i, j] = op;
                    if (i == j)
                    {
                        if (op == del)
                            ++deletions;
                        else if (op == ins)
                            ++insertions;
                        else
                            ++substitutions;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I've tried this with an example of "hello" and "hello" and it adds up on deletions and insertions when it's correct. This is the sort of thing I need just not sure this bit is exactly working!

Comment: Deletion and insertion both spit out the number 9 when the "hello" is correct?

Comment: The basic problem is that I misunderstood what was happening. In the code, you only want to increment the deletions, insertions, etc. when `i == j`. At least, I think that's what the problem is. You might have to experiment with it. I made the change to my code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a play around and see if that's what I need.

Comment: Sorry I seemed snappy before, it's 1:23 here and getting pretty tired.
The problem I'm getting with this is if the word I insert is shorter than hello, for example "hllo" it says there's an insertion and substitute. How can this be solved?